# Jewish prayer services in Heathrow Airport

Tags: airports, lhr, religion

Many airports have either a multi-faith prayer room (Luton, Zurich) or separate rooms for several different faiths (JFK). Does Heathrow have either of these, and do they have set times for Jewish prayers, either in this room or somewhere else?
I will be transferring there and need an afternoon service.

Alternatively, what is the nearest scheduled early afternoon prayers to Heathrow?

Answer (score 5):

According to [the LHR site on prayer rooms](http://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/terminal-facilities-and-services/prayer-rooms-and-chapel) there are both multi-faith prayer rooms and chaplains available:

> ### Prayer rooms in the terminals
>
> There are multi-faith prayer rooms in each terminal at Heathrow, offering a quiet retreat for prayer and meditation:
>
> - Terminal 2: departures (after security), near Gate A21 [[map](http://maps.heathrow.com/index.php?zoom=14&area=204&lat=51.46912434676542&lng=-0.44956846515846393)]
> - Terminal 2: T2B (after security), between Gates B34 and B35 [[map](http://maps.heathrow.com/index.php?zoom=14&area=206&lat=51.47167959075545&lng=-0.44291137451601753)]
> - Terminal 3: departures, Level 1 (before security) [[map](http://maps.heathrow.com/index.php?zoom=14&area=56&subarea=56&lat=51.47135302921957&lng=-0.4579479593468458)]
> - Terminal 3: departures (after security), near Lounge A [[map](http://maps.heathrow.com/index.php?zoom=14&area=58&gid=t3_dep_x507111y175774i16378vc_14)]
> - Terminal 4: mezzanine floor (before security), near Yotel [[map](http://maps.heathrow.com/index.php?zoom=15&area=81&subarea=80&lat=51.459833557184844&lng=-0.4466847081252533&pindrop=1)]
> - Terminal 4: departures (after security), near Gates 3 and 4 [[map](http://maps.heathrow.com/index.php?zoom=14&area=83&gid=t4_dep_x507774y174381i16778_14)]
> - Terminal 5: check-in Zone A (before security) [[map](http://maps.heathrow.com/index.php?zoom=14&area=31&lat=51.4732091566924&lng=-0.4882052318733407)]
> - Terminal 5: departures (after security), near Gate A8 [[map](http://maps.heathrow.com/index.php?zoom=14&area=35&lat=51.47288451705026&lng=-0.4867299483734778)]
> - Terminal 5: T5B (after security), near Gate B34 [[map](http://maps.heathrow.com/index.php?zoom=14&area=37&lat=51.471696542106194&lng=-0.4808162714977152)]
> - Terminal 5: T5C (after security), near Gate C52 [[map](http://maps.heathrow.com/index.php?zoom=14&area=38&lat=51.47015716272144&lng=-0.4756908522775463)]
>
> ### Airport chaplains
>
> Heathrow has Christian Chaplains from Anglican, Catholic and Free Church denominations, and faith representatives from the Buddhist, Hindu, Jewish, Muslim and Sikh faiths. To get in touch call +44 (0)20 8745 4261, or email at chapel@heathrow.com.

The Lead Jewish Chaplain is:

> Jewish: Rabbi Hershi Vogel (mob: 07970 829758)